# Dropbox shutdown webhooks for an user

Tags: dropbox, webhooks

I have dropbox webhooks. When a user make a change, this webhook sends me a json with the list of users that have changes.

If some user in my platform, that has the drobox active, doesn't pay the quota so it's "inactive", there's a way to stop receiving his webhooks?

The only solution that I've thought is to store the inactive users and ignore when his id is equals to the id on the json, but that's quite ineficient because if I have 1000 users inactive that's a huge amount of webhooks to ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to exclude users that are over quota from webhook notifications. We'll consider it a feature request.